# Why isn't my JS code working? I'm trying to get this code to generate a random password

Tags: javascript, passwords, generator

EDIT:  Made some changes, now when I click generate password, I get back 'undefined'.  Progress!

EDIT #2:  Now I am not getting 'undefined' when I click, but devtools says at line 26 i am exceeding maximum call stack.  How do I fix that?

Javascript is really hard, man. I'm trying to get this code to generate a random password.  When I click the generate password button, nothing happens. Chrome dev tools doesn't show any issues.  I just started learning javascript a week ago.  I need to add more details to post this so...I think I just threw in everything I 'learned' in here, so it's probably really messed up.

```
// Assignment code here
var length;
var number;
var specialCharacter;
var upperCase;
var lowåerCase;
var selection;
var lettersUp

const characters = ["number", "letters", "character"];

number = "0123456789";
letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
character = "!@#$%^&*)(";
// Get references to the #generate element
var generateBtn = document.querySelector("#generate");
// Write password to the #password input
function writePassword() {
  var password = generatePassword();
  var passwordText = document.querySelector("#password");

  passwordText.value = password;
}
// Begin setting password parameters
function generatePassword() {
  document.getElementById("click", generatePassword); {
    for ( let i = 0; i < length; i++ ) {
      console.log(password);
    }
  }

  // Select # of characters for new password
  length = prompt("Enter the number of characters you'd like for your new password (Select a number between 8-128)");
  if (!length) {
    alert("Please make a valid entry");
  } else if (length < 8 || length > 128) {
    // Function recognizes incorrect input
    length = prompt("New password must be from 8-128 characters");
  } else {
    // Prompts continue when length input is valid
    number = confirm("Include numbers in your new password?");
    specialCharacter = confirm("Include special characters in your new password?");
    upperCase = confirm("Include uppercase letters?");
    lowerCase = confirm("Include lowercase letters?");
  };
  // for all of the above true
  if (number && specialCharacter && upperCase && lowerCase) {
    selection = character.concat(number,letters,lettersUp);
  }
  // three options selected
  else if (number && specialCharacter && upperCase) {
    selection = character.concat(number, lettersUp);
  }
  else if (specialCharacter && upperCase && lowerCase) {
    selection = character.concat(letters, lettersUp);
  }
  else if (upperCase && lowerCase && number) {
    selection = lettersUp.concat(letters, number);
  }
  else if (lowerCase && number && specialCharacter) {
    selection = letters.concat(number, character);
  }
  //two options selected
  else if (specialCharacter && number) {
    selection = character.concat(number);
  }
  else if (number && upperCase) {
    selection = number.concat(lettersUp);
  }
  else if (upperCase && lowerCase) {
    selection = lettersUp.concat(letters);
  }
  else if (lowerCase && number) {
    selection = letters.concat(number);
  }
  else if (lowerCase && specialCharacter) {
    selection = letters.concat(character);
  }
  else if (specialCharacter && upperCase) {
    selection = character.concat(lettersUp);
  }
  //one option
  else if (specialCharacter) {
    selection = character;
  }
  else if (number) {
    selection = number;
  }
  else if (lowerCase) {
    selection = letters;
  }
  else if (upperCase) {
    selection = lettersUp;
  };

  
}

generatePassword();

// Add event listener to generate button
generateBtn.addEventListener("click", writePassword);
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Password Generator</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/css/style.css" />
</head>
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <header>
      <h1>Password Generator</h1>
    </header>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-header">
        <h2>Generate a Password</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body">
        <textarea
          readonly
          id="password"
          placeholder="Your Secure Password"
          aria-label="Generated Password"
        ></textarea>
      </div>
      <div class="card-footer">
        <button id="generate" class="btn">Generate Password</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="./assets/js/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is `charactersLength`? What is `document.getElementById("click", generatePassword); {` supposed to be doing?

Comment: I fixed that, I think?  // Begin setting password parameters
function generatePassword() {
  document.getElementById("click", generatePassword); {
    for ( let i = 0; i < length; i++ ) {
      console.log(password);
    }
  }

Comment: surely you want `document.getElementById('generate').addEventListener('click', () => {...}); `

Comment: `document.getElementById` accepts only one parameter,  the id of the required element. It doesn't execute any function

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to return in `generatePassword()`. Also I guess you forgot to initialize `lettersUp`. I fixed that for you. Maybe you want to shuffle the string and use `substr` to extract only a substring with a certain length afterward. Also as a reminder, there is a strange character in your `lowerCase` variable originally. Double-check if that is intended.

```js
// Assignment code here
var length;
var number;
var specialCharacter;
var upperCase;
var lowerCase;
var selection;
var lettersUp

const characters = ["number", "letters", "character"];

number = "0123456789";
letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
lettersUp = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
character = "!@#$%^&*)()";
// Get references to the #generate element
var generateBtn = document.querySelector("#generate");
// Write password to the #password input
function writePassword() {
  var password = generatePassword();
  var passwordText = document.querySelector("#password");
  passwordText.value = password;
}
// Begin setting password parameters
function generatePassword() {
  // Select # of characters for new password
  length = prompt("Enter the number of characters you'd like for your new password (Select a number between 8-128)");
  if (!length) {
    alert("Please make a valid entry");
  } else if (length < 8 || length > 128) {
    // Function recognizes incorrect input
    length = prompt("New password must be from 8-128 characters");
  } else {
    // Prompts continue when length input is valid
    number = confirm("Include numbers in your new password?");
    specialCharacter = confirm("Include special characters in your new password?");
    upperCase = confirm("Include uppercase letters?");
    lowerCase = confirm("Include lowercase letters?");
  };
  // for all of the above true
  if (number && specialCharacter && upperCase && lowerCase) {
    selection = character.concat(number, letters, lettersUp);
  }
  // three options selected
  else if (number && specialCharacter && upperCase) {
    selection = character.concat(number, lettersUp);
  } else if (specialCharacter && upperCase && lowerCase) {
    selection = character.concat(letters, lettersUp);
  } else if (upperCase && lowerCase && number) {
    selection = lettersUp.concat(letters, number);
  } else if (lowerCase && number && specialCharacter) {
    selection = letters.concat(number, character);
  }
  //two options selected
  else if (specialCharacter && number) {
    selection = character.concat(number);
  } else if (number && upperCase) {
    selection = number.concat(lettersUp);
  } else if (upperCase && lowerCase) {
    selection = lettersUp.concat(letters);
  } else if (lowerCase && number) {
    selection = letters.concat(number);
  } else if (lowerCase && specialCharacter) {
    selection = letters.concat(character);
  } else if (specialCharacter && upperCase) {
    selection = character.concat(lettersUp);
  }
  //one option
  else if (specialCharacter) {
    selection = character;
  } else if (number) {
    selection = number;
  } else if (lowerCase) {
    selection = letters;
  } else if (upperCase) {
    selection = lettersUp;
  };
  return selection;
}

// Add event listener to generate button
generateBtn.addEventListener("click", writePassword);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Password Generator</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/css/style.css" />
</head>
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <header>
      <h1>Password Generator</h1>
    </header>
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-header">
        <h2>Generate a Password</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body">
        <textarea
          readonly
          id="password"
          placeholder="Your Secure Password"
          aria-label="Generated Password"
        ></textarea>
      </div>
      <div class="card-footer">
        <button id="generate" class="btn">Generate Password</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="./assets/js/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi @serpothos if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.